# add elements to new vector up to a certain value

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following vector:

```r
tst <- seq(1, 100, 1)
```

I want to make a new vector which has all the negative difference values of every element in that vector with each other, but only differences which are between 0 & -8. I could do this as follows:

```r
m <- matrix(NA, length(tst), length(tst))
for(i in 1:length(tst)) {
  for(j in 1:length(tst)) {
    m[i, j] <- tst[i] - tst[j]
    m[m == 0] <- NA
    m[m > 8] <- NA
    m[m < -8] <- NA 
  }
}

m <- c(m)
```

the problem is my data is too large (tst length as big as ~650,000) to make these matrices, so the only way I can generate my vector `m` is to just include relevant differences (between -8 and 8) - n.b. the vector `m` will contain a positive and negative value of each difference. So will have a mean of zero and will be a symmetrical histogram.

So i need something like:

```r
for(i in 1:length(tst)) {
  for(j in 1:length(tst)) {
    while(tst[i] - tst[i:length(tst)]) {
      m <- tst[i] - tst[i:length(tst)]; if(tst[i]-tst[1:length(tst)] < -8; break)
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: `m = unlist(sapply(tst, '-', tst))` ? is this ? this is a vector of all combination of differences. then you subset using `m[m < 0 & m > -8]`

Comment: @joel.wilson - `unlist()` doesn't do anything there.  `sapply()` gives a matrix.  I think you want `c()`, but it's not even necessary to wrap `sapply()` at all.

Comment: Joel's code did work - thanks! Mine did the same thing (i.e. made a matrix) but took ages

Comment: @RichScriven sorry for the late reply! you are absolutely right.... actually i had `as.vector` there but i mistakenly pasted the first attempt code here..even `c()` shall work..

Comment: @Charlie did it give the results you are looking for? and were you able to understand what `sapply()` is doing? it's also a loop in a way

Comment: The memory space did max out for some of my larger samples although I still had a large enough sample. sapply() applies a subtraction function to tst x tst?